# Can't access sql plus terminal

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, oracle19c

I forgot my sql username and password. I checked online to login through sysdba. But the problem is it always prompts me to ty pe username and password and doesn't let me enter any other command. For your reference the ss:

[image]

I want something like :

sql>

where I can enter commands like sqlplus / as sysdba
How do I get that from here?

Comment: In your screen shot, you did not include the actual, full, complete, exact command you issued at the OS prompt in order to launch sqlplus.  That said, if you forgot your password, your only recourse is to connect to the database as SYS, then issue an ALTER USER command to reset the password for the user in question.  And this time, make a note of the password you used.  There is no way to recover a forgotten password in oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use *SQL Plus Terminal* - open **operating system command prompt**, and then

```
C:\>sqlplus / as sysdba
```